# Getting Cookies from Headless ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am trying to use the `driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed()` method on a headless `ChromeDriver`, but it seems to not return any cookies when the driver is in headless mode. 

Is there a way around that? 

I am trying to do some automation but I don't want to show the browser when the `Navigate().GoToUrl()` method is executed.

```
public static ChromeDriver NavigateDriver(string url)
{
  var options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.AddArgument("--headless");
  options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
  var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
  return driver;
}

public static string GetCookieFromDriverInitial(ChromeDriver driver)
{
  string cookie;
  cookie = Convert.ToString(driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("bm_sv"));
  return cookie;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we are able to help you.

Comment: @DanielSchütte - Added code

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium developers recently added a **2nd** headless mode (in 2021). See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

They later renamed the option in 2023 for Chrome 109 -> https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/e9c516118e2e1923757ecb13e6d9fff36775d1f4

For Chrome 109 and above, the `--headless=new` flag will now allow you to get the full functionality of Chrome in the new headless mode. (For Chrome versions 96 through 108, use `--headless=chrome`)

In your example, you want to use:

```cs
options.AddArgument("--headless=new");
```

If something works with regular Chrome, it should now work with the newer headless mode too.